# Scroll down inside a div to 25px

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an element `div#container` which is scrollable. How can I scroll it down via native javascript to `25px`? My markup is the following:

```
<div id = "container" style="overflow: auto;">
    <div class="filter-container" style="display: block;">
        <!-- content -->
    </div>
    <div class="filter-container" style="display: block;">
        <!-- content -->
    </div>
    <div class="filter-container" style="display: block;">
        <!-- content -->
    </div>
    <div class="filter-container" style="display: block;">
        <!-- content -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show some code

Comment: @kapantzak what code?

Comment: Show us what is the markup and what have you tried so far so we can be specific

Comment: @user3663882 The HTML for your website where you want to scroll down and the JavaScript you've tried so far. You have to create a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for Javascript `Element.scrollLeft()` or `Element.scrollTop()`.

Look up what you need here: [w3schools DOM Element](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp)

Answer (score 1):

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Scroll () {
        var myCont = document.getElementById ("container");
        myCont.scrollLeft = 10;
        myCont.scrollTop = 40;
    }
</script>
</head> 
<body>

 <div id="container" style="overflow:scroll; width:150px; height:80px; white-space:nowrap background-color:#e0f0e0;">

     1. line with a long content <br />
     2. line with a long content <br />
     3. line with a long content <br />
     4. line with a long content <br />
     5. line with a long content <br />
     6. line with a long content <br />
     7. line with a long content <br />
     8. line with a long content <br />
     9. line with a long content <br />
</div>

    <button onclick="Scroll ();">Scroll the element above!</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
document.getElementById("container").scrollTop=25;
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xL2n69wL/1/)**

Or with jQuery

```
$("#container").scrollTop(25);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function scrollToElement(element) {    
    var positionX = 0,         
        positionY = 25;    

    while(element != null){        
        positionX += element.offsetLeft;        
        positionY += element.offsetTop;        
        element = element.offsetParent;        
        window.scrollTo(positionX, positionY);    
    }
}

var element = document.getElementById("container");
scrollToElement(element);
```

```html
<div id = "container" style="overflow: auto;">
    <div class="filter-container" style="display: block;">
       test1
    </div>
    <div class="filter-container" style="display: block;">
      test2
    </div>
    <div class="filter-container" style="display: block;">
        ttest3
    </div>
    <div class="filter-container" style="display: block;">
        test4
    </div>
</div>
```